# Let's synonymize [postfix-notation] and [reverse-polish-notation]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[reverse-polish-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reverse-polish-notation) has 28 question and the appropriate excerpt (no wiki):

> Reverse Polish Notation is a mathematical notation where each operator follows all of its operands. It is particularly useful in programing, as it lends itself to algorithms extremely simply.

[postfix-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-notation) has 233 questions and the excerpt (no wiki):

> Postfix notation (also known as Reverse Polish Notation, RPN) is a mathematical notation wherein every operator follows all of its operands, in contrast to Polish notation, which puts the operator in the prefix position.

As should be easy to see, they are exactly the same.

Thus, could someone [please synonymize](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postfix-notation/synonyms) reverse-polish-notation to postfix-notation?

Comment: I think a moderator should do this. With the small volume of questions, I think there are very few people who have enough votes to suggest synonym.

Comment: An alternative is to retag the 28 reverse-polish-notation questions. But I suppose a synonym will help prevent this in future.