# Fix [postfix] mail server tag; disambiguate vs [infix]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

The [postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix) tag is described as pertaining to the [Postfix mail server](http://www.postfix.org) but gets a steady stream of questions about postfix vs. infix notation, typically then also with [infix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infix) and one of [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), or [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Rather than manually removing the [postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix) tag from all those questions, I would like to propose a change to clarify the purpose of these tags.

My suggested set of actions would be

- Rename [postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix) -> [postfix-mta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-mta)
- For consistency with the existing [postfix-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-notation), rename [infix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infix) -> [infix-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infix-notation) and redirect the old name as a synonym

I originally wanted to suggest burnination of [infix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infix) altogether; it is unclear whether it serves any useful purpose.  But given that [postfix-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix-notation) exists (see also [synonymize `postfix-notation` with `reverse-polish-notation`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274995/lets-synonymize-postfix-notation-and-reverse-polish-notation) from last October; [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)) perhaps I am being too harsh.

While thinking about posting this suggestion, I also originally wanted to nominate [postfix] as a synonym for [postfix-mta]  but on closer thought, it should simply be abandoned, in favor of having two disambiguated tags for the two different purposes.

Comment: I originally had `postfix-server` but I think `postfix-mta` describes the entire software package better.  For anybody actually using the software, the acronym for the term "mail transport agent" should be reasonably familiar.

Comment: Do you want infix synonymized or renamed? I would tend for the latter in this case, as there will then be two longer tags. And if all questions in postfix are now about the mta, ask a mod for the rename.

Comment: I thought that's what I'm doing here, with the additional benefit of an open discussion. But if there are no downvotes, I suppose I can proceed with this. I have not cleaned out all postfix questions which are actually about postfix-notation. I'll work on that.

Comment: Okay; I have gone over the [tag:postfix] questions and retagged a whole bunch to [tag:postfix-notation] or [tag:postfix-operator] where pertinent.  There may still be stray questions which are not about Postfix the MTA but they can be fixed as they are discovered.

Comment: I flagged [a postfix question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657268/iredmail-and-mysql-issues) for moderator attention and requested a rename to [tag:postfix-mta].

Comment: Flagged [an infix question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586287/infix-to-postfix-conversion-in-python) with a similar rename request for [tag:infix-notation].

Comment: The change seems to have been reverted on July 8 or thereabouts.  The [tag:postfix] tag is a morass of off-topic questions anyway.  Found [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455983/postfix-regex-and-catastrophic-backtracking) which was marginally acceptable for Stack Overflow and tagged for moderator attention, asking what's up with the tag rename.

Comment: @tripleee - You might want to have a conversation with this person: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38282541/revisions , because they recreated the tag. Should I just make [postfix] a synonym of [postfix-mta] and be done with it?

Comment: @BradLarson merging should be more appropiated, since people would use postfix for the notation and be retagged postfix-mta.

Comment: @BradLarson The user in question does not seem to have any involvement at all in the tag, other than as creator of the redundant tag description. It's different (and in some ways more informative) than http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postfix-mta/info but based on the earlier consensus, the two should be merged, like Braiam says.

Comment: See also now the linked question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332532/synonym-postfix-postfix-mta-seems-to-have-been-reverted?noredirect=1&lq=1