# Synonym [postfix] -> [postfix-mta] seems to have been reverted

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

The [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) rename and synonym mapping requested in [Fix [postfix] mail server tag; disambiguate vs [infix]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290566/fix-postfix-mail-server-tag-disambiguate-vs-infix) seems to have been reverted.  Starting July 10th, questions have been pouring into the [postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postfix) tag again.

Was the synonym reverted, or never implemented?

Comment: I suggest we burninate the tag by closing and deleting all questions about the mail server and retagging all questions about the operator notation, then request the tag to be blacklisted.

Comment: Yeah, most (though not 100%) of the questions here about Postfix really belong on Super User or Server Fault, and the current tagging on them is a mess.

Comment: Whatever originally happened, I have now created a synonym proposal and updated the [tag:postfix] tag info to hopefully dissuade some people from using it.